# NativeScript push-plugin not displaying notifications on the notification bar

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm using NativeScript's [`push-plugin`](https://github.com/NativeScript/push-plugin) to receive notifications [sent from Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)](https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send):

```
public constructor(
    private _services: PushService,
) {
    const settings = {
        senderID: "XXXXXXXX",
        badge: true,
        clearBadge: true,
        sound: true,
        alert: true,
        interactiveSettings: {
            actions: [{
                identifier: 'READ_IDENTIFIER',
                title: 'Read',
                activationMode: "foreground",
                destructive: false,
                authenticationRequired: true,
            }, {
                identifier: 'CANCEL_IDENTIFIER',
                title: 'Cancel',
                activationMode: "foreground",
                destructive: true,
                authenticationRequired: true,
            }],
            categories: [{
                identifier: 'READ_CATEGORY',
                actionsForDefaultContext: ['READ_IDENTIFIER', 'CANCEL_IDENTIFIER'],
                actionsForMinimalContext: ['READ_IDENTIFIER', 'CANCEL_IDENTIFIER'],
            }],
        },
        notificationCallbackIOS: data => {
            console.log("DATA: " + JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        notificationCallbackAndroid: (message, data, notification) => {
            console.log("MESSAGE: " + JSON.stringify(message));
            console.log("DATA: " + JSON.stringify(data));
            console.log("NOTIFICATION: " + JSON.stringify(notification));

            alert(message);
        },
    };

    PushNotifications.register(settings, data => {
        console.log("REGISTRATION ID: " + data);

        this.toDeviceToken = data;

        PushNotifications.onMessageReceived(settings.notificationCallbackAndroid);
    }, error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Using this code, I can receive the success message in `notificationCallbackAndroid` method when I send them from Postman. This is what I get on the logs:

```
{
    "multicast_id": 8382252195536318747,
    "success": 1,
    "failure": 0,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "message_id": "0:1521270133609562%161a06bff9fd7ecd"
        }
    ]
}
```

However, no notification shows up in the notification bar.

Do we have to use the separate method to show the notification?

Comment: I am trying to implement this by creating a new IntentService and BroadcastReceiver as mentioned here - https://www.nativescript.org/blog/using-android-background-services-in-nativescript If you have already implemented the same, please share information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`push-plugin`](https://github.com/NativeScript/push-plugin) will not create/display a notification automatically, it will just notify you when a notification is received.

You need to use another plugin, [`nativescript-local-notifications`](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-local-notifications), to create/display it. So, inside your `notificationCallbackAndroid` and `notificationCallbackIOS` you should have something like this:

```
LocalNotifications.schedule([{
    title: notificationData.title,
    body: notificationData.body,
}]);
```

Also, `onMessageReceived` has been deprecated, now you should only use `notificationCallbackAndroid` and/or `notificationCallbackIOS`, so once you update `push-plugin` to the latest version, you can get rid of this line:

```
PushNotifications.onMessageReceived(settings.notificationCallbackAndroid);
```

Answer (score 1):

To add, it seems notifications work perfectly on iOS. But on Android, it only works when application is active.

Some forums state that the push payload needs a "notification" structure to automatically add to the notification tray, but i looked over the commit history and it looks like it has been (attempted) fixed.

Either way, i'm using the same push sending SDK with another app development sdk (Xamarin) and don't want custom code to send a different payload on Nativescript apps.

I will try Danzigers answer as Android-only code and see if it helps. If not I will try to revert to an older version of this plugin, as I understand the entire problem is a regression.

PS. I see that this plugin has been obsoleted in favor of the firebase plugin, but i still like the simplicity (and smaller footprint?) of this one when only needing GCM and APS.

**UPDATE**

Installed local-notifications plugin, and added code for using it on Android only, and all is well.